# Plot boxplot in R with temperature records by years and months

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a dataset with temperature records like:

```
    row.names   Collection_date temprature  col_yr  col_mnth
    1   1       4-Aug-04          27        2004    8
    2   2       9-Aug-04          26        2004    8
    3   3       4-Aug-04          27        2004    8
    4   4       9-Aug-04          26        2004    8
    5   5       9-Aug-04          26        2004    8
    6   6       9-Aug-04          26        2004    8
...
1031 1031       6-Aug-06          32        2006    8
```

I want to create boxplot in R with x axis like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
        2004                         2005
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a very elegant solution but it is the only I could think of so that your boxplots had the proper width.

Given your sample data:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("row.names   Collection_date temprature  col_yr  col_mnth
  1   1   4-Aug-04    27  2004    8
  2   2   9-Aug-04    26  2004    8
  3   3   4-Aug-04    27  2004    8
  4   4   9-Aug-04    26  2004    8
  5   5   9-Aug-04    26  2004    8
  6   6   9-Aug-04    26  2004    8
  1031 1031   6-Aug-06    32    2006    8"))
```

First declare your dates as POSIXct objects (beware that in your case you have to be sure that your locale settings are in English since your months are abbreviated in english):

```
dat$Collection_date <- strptime(dat$Collection_date,"%d-%b-%y")
```

Then create sequences of months and years:

```
ax_month <- seq(min(dat$Collection_date),max(dat$Collection_date),"month")
ax_year <- seq(min(dat$Collection_date),max(dat$Collection_date),"year")
```

Then draw an empty plot with your axes:

```
plot(NA, xaxt="n",type="n", ylab="Temperature", xlab=NA,
     xlim=range(seq_along(ax_month)), ylim=range(dat$temprature))
axis(3,at=seq_along(ax_month), labels=format(ax_month,"%m"))
mtext(format(ax_year,"%Y"), side=3, line=3, at=seq(1,length(ax_month), by=12))
```

And finally the monthly boxplots:

```
for(i in seq_along(ax_month)){
    sub_dat <- dat[format(dat$Collection_date, "%m-%Y") == format(ax_month[i], "%m-%Y"),]
    boxplot(sub_dat$temprature, add=TRUE, axes=FALSE, at=i)
    }
```

Obviously given the sample of data you gave, the result here is not very pretty but I guess that's with the actual data it will be nicely filled up.

[image]

But here is what it would look like with some (made-up) more complete data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. I tried this code. I could plot the grid, but the loop gives an error:     Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: I could menage it finally. Thank you.